# Dart creating constructor without this keyword

Tags: flutter, list, dart, initializer

I could not get the constructor logic with the below code block. In the named constructors we use ClassName({this.variable or required this.variable}); But, in the below example the developer choose a different way. It uses initializer list too but could not get the logic why it defines a variable like this

> MetaWeatherApiClient? weatherApiClient

in the constructor's body?

```
class WeatherRepository {
  WeatherRepository({
    MetaWeatherApiClient? weatherApiClient
  }) : _weatherApiClient = weatherApiClient ?? MetaWeatherApiClient();

  final MetaWeatherApiClient _weatherApiClient;

  Future<Weather> getWeather(String city) async {
    final location = await _weatherApiClient.locationSearch(city);
    final woeid = location.woeid;
    final weather = await _weatherApiClient.getWeather(woeid);
    return Weather(
      temperature: weather.theTemp,
      location: location.title,
      condition: weather.weatherStateAbbr.toCondition,
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a code like shown below

```dart
class SomeClass {
  SomeClass({
    required this.a,
  });

  final int a;
}
```

Now when you initialize the SomeClass object, you will have to do this.

```dart
final obj = SomeClass(a: 1);
```

i.e. you will manually need to pass the constructor parameter in this case.

But if I did something like this

```dart
class SomeClass {
  SomeClass({int? a}) : _a = a ?? 1;

  final int _a;
}
```

Now if I wanted to create an instance of `SomeClass`, I can just do,

```dart
final obj = SomeClass();
```

Here, I don't need to pass the constructor parameter as the constructor parameter is nullable. And in the initializer list I have a condition that if the parameter is null, assign the default value as 1.

In the code that you shared, you can make a `WeatherRepository` instance simply by doing

```dart
final obj = WeatherRepository();
```

You needn't explicitly mention the dependency of `WeatherRepository` as it is a nullable variable and when it is `null` the condition in the initializer list will anyhow initialize the dependency.

You didn't have to do this to create an instance of `WeatherRepository`.

```dart
final obj = WeatherRepository(MetaWeatherApiClient());
```

Ultimately helping to write clean and readable code (at least when object initialization needs to take place)

In the case you don't know how the expression

```dart
var a = b ?? c;
```

works, then this is equivalent to

```dart
if(b != null) {
  var a = b;
} else {
  var a = c;
}
```